# How do I convert NSData to NSDictionary using NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Hi I am facing problem in conversion of `NSData` to `NSDictionary` using `NSJSONSerialization`?

I got data using my code but unable to convert it into json.

Here is my code...

**ViewController.h** File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
    NSString *massage;
    NSURL *url;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableData *httpbody;
    NSMutableData *webData;
    NSData *responceData;
    NSDictionary *responceJson;
}
```

and **ViewController.m** File

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *mobile = @"123456789";

    NSString *password = @"Welcome123";

    NSString *deviceId = @"123sdfg15641ert321ret";


    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://203.109.87.34:8585/d-cab/web/app_dev.php/api/v1"];

    massage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"action\":\"login\",\"data\":{\"contact\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\",\"deviceId\":\"%@\"}}",mobile,password,deviceId];
    //NSLog(@"Body = %@", massage);
    httpbody = [ NSMutableData dataWithBytes: [ massage UTF8String ] length: [ massage length ] ];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: httpbody];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:10.0];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    //NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    //[connection start];
    if (connection) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }

}

#pragma mark NSURLConnection Delegate Methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [webData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [webData appendData:data];
    //NSLog(@"WebData = %@",webData);
    //NSLog(@"=================================");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSError* error = nil;
    responceJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"ResponceJSON = %@",responceJson);

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // Show error message
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error In connection" message:@"We are facing some problem in connection. Please Check your Internet Connection." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Please Check my code and tell me where and what change I have to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Thanks to all who gave attention to my question....
 But I found the problem in my question.
I am trying to send the parameter into string format instead of dictionary format and not specifying header to request.
 Here is my updated code...

```
NSDictionary *paramData = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:mobile,@"contact",password,@"password",deviceId,@"deviceId", nil];
    //NSLog(@"paramData = %@",paramData);
    jsonParam = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"login",@"action",paramData,@"data", nil];
    //NSLog(@"jsonParam = %@",jsonParam);

    httpbody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonParam options:0 error:nil];

    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [httpbody length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: httpbody];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
```

It worked for me....

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code :

```
responceJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData
                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                    error:&error];
```

Comment: this method also was not working it give me "null" value in "responceJson"

Comment: you tried printing data in didReceiveData and after appending is webData properly updated ?

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem here is not in conversion problem is in this funtion

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
//[webData setLength:0];
webdData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
```

It will help.Thanks

Comment: this method also was not working it give me "null" value in "responceJson"

Comment: than problem is in your request check if its properly

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE TELL ME EROOR IN REQUEST OR GIVE ME AN EXAMPLE

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if( theConnection )
    {
         mdata = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    mdata.length=0;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [mdata appendData:data];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Data store in dictionary when connection proceed in background

    dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mdata options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);
 }
```

This is working gooood...

Comment: print the receive data in -connection didReceiveData {    NSString *ss=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:mcntdata encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"ss:-%@",ss);}  and see that string is null or what..

Comment: Can u tell me your parameters and value and url so i can check it in postman.

Comment: here is parameter string
{"action":"login","data":{"contact":"123456789","password":"Welcome123","deviceId":"123sdfg15641ert321ret"}}

Comment: You are getting html code which mean your parameter or values are not correct.

Comment: in my code
massage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"action\":\"login\",\"data\":{\"contact\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\",\"deviceId\":\"%@\"}}",mobile,password,deviceId];

Comment: it creates parameter string

Comment: Try this NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"action=%@&contact=%@",txt_password.text,txt_email.text];            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];                Put your all parameter.

Comment: @Diwakar what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check, what your connection is load. Converting NSData to NSString. In didFinishLoading typing this:

```
NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"loaded data: %@",tempString);
```